# Remove all text content from HTML div but keep HTML tags and structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have:

```
<div>
    Here
    <a href="#"> is </a>
    <p> Text, that I want to </p>
    be removed
</div>
```

I want:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"> </a>
    <p> </p>
</div>
```

What is the easiest way to remove all text, but keep the HTML Structure?

Comment: you could use: `.empty()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a function/plugin that will recurse through elements in your top level element, removing any text nodes found:

```
$.fn.removeText = function(){
  this.each(function(){

     // Get elements contents
     var $cont = $(this).contents();

      // Loop through the contents
      $cont.each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);

          // If it's a text node
          if(this.nodeType == 3){
            $this.remove(); // Remove it 
          } else if(this.nodeType == 1){ // If its an element node
            $this.removeText(); //Recurse
          }
      });
  });
}

$('#toplevel').removeText();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/tooe826z/1/)

**Reference:**

- [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 5):

Plain javascript, recursive solution:

```
function removeAllText(element) {

    // loop through all the nodes of the element
    var nodes = element.childNodes;

    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

        var node = nodes[i];

        // if it's a text node, remove it
        if(node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {

            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);


            i--; // have to update our incrementor since we just removed a node from childNodes

        } else

        // if it's an element, repeat this process
        if(node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            removeAllText(node);

        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing');
removeAllText(thing);
```

Pretty simple

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted...this is the best answer

Comment: No idea who and why downvoted it. However, this doesn't solve the entire problem. You need to remove the worlds `Here` and  `be removed` as well. :)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Then he can iterate through the childNodes instead? This is a clean, vanilla js solution.

Comment: I mean, he can add ids, OP's code have no ids at all. And he's like.. not iterating..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent
IE9+, and every version of Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera. So yea, pretty good.

Comment: @Maverick Good catch, I updated it with a recursive solution.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you want to remove all text nodes from the element. You can access text nodes using [`jQuery.contents`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) function. And you do not need any recursion. jQuery does it for you:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#to-clean, #to-clean *")                  // selects the element and all element nodes inside it
    .contents()                                // selects all child nodes including tags, comments and text
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; // filter text nodes
    }).remove();                               // boom!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="to-clean">
  Here
  <a href="#"> is </a>
  <p>Text, that I want to</p>
  be removed
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the easiest and cleanest method! Just few minutes after second correct answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One more method, just for fun and learning purposes. Tried to do it without using of native JS functions, checking of element properties...Surprisingly, it works.

```
clones=[];

$('div').children().each(function() {

clones.push($(this).clone().text(''));
});

$('div').empty();

for(i=0;i<clones.length;i++) {

 clones[i].appendTo('div');
}
```

JQuery doesn't count pure text nodes as child elements of container, so we can use this behavior, too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/djvhxgm9/

Answer (score 0):

```
function RemoveText(el){
   el.children().each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.children().length > 0){
       $this.children().each(RemoveText($this));
     }
     else{
       $this.text("");
     }     
   });
}
```

Comment: Use `.text("")` instead of `empty()`. empty() is for remove elements, not text content.

Comment: will edit, together with checking if we have children elements to maybe make a recursion

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function empty(e) {
    var childs = e.children;
    for(var i=0;i<childs.length;i++) {
        if(childs[i].children.length!=0) {
            childs[i].innerHTML=" ";
        } else {
            empty(childs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the current node has zero childNodes and the nodeType equals three then set the textContent as an empty string

```js
const removeAllInnerText = (element) => {
  const nodes = element.childNodes;

  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.childNodes.length > 0) {
      removeAllInnerText(node);
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      node.textContent = "";
    }
  });
};

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
removeAllInnerText(container);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script defer src="./index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      Here
      <a href="#"> is </a>
      <p>Text, that I want to</p>
      be removed
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

use jquery .empty() method

https://api.jquery.com/empty/   << api reference for jquery

example:

```
<!--input-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$( ".hello" ).empty();

<!--result-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will remove child elements also.