# How can i remove just the text from link

Tags: javascript

I need to remove just the text (    Ajouter aux favoris
) in the link above, without removing the span or other tags inside using javascript (no jquery).

The problem is, this only applies to a single element (screenshot below)

i have 6 div `(.syno21-teaser--item)`, each one have `<div class="syno21-actu--favoris">`

```
        <div class="syno21-teaser--wrapper">
    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>


    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>


    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>


    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>


    <div class="syno21-teaser--item">
        <article data-history-node-id="2451" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2451" role="article" class="contextual-region" about="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="1">
            <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2451:changed=1552987642&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="UYOdl1jQW4O3NVY1yTvlA--KZZuSPgLUQSj9L44auww" class="contextual">
                <button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">options de configuration Ouvert
                </button>
                <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
                    <li class="entitynodeedit-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/edit?destination=/node/2681">Modifier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="entitynodedelete-form">
                        <a href="/node/2451/delete?destination=/node/2681">Supprimer</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="syno21-actu--teaser">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_img/fr/teaser">
                        <img src="/sites/synoptic/files/styles/bloc_actualite/public/securite_reseau_0_1.png?itok=zGIhuZxv" width="353" height="209" typeof="foaf:Image">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="syno21-actu--date-Thematique">
                    <div class="syno21-actu--date">
                        19 mars 2019
                    </div>
                    <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/field_synoptic_thematique/fr/teaser">
                        <div>
                            <a href="/taxonomy/term/20" hreflang="fr">Cybersécurité</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-vues-likes-favoris">
                    <span class="responsable">Responsable : Crosnier, Florian</span>
                </div>

                <div class="syno21-actu--vues"></div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--likes">
                    <div class="content-like text-center mt-20 mb-30">
                        <div class="flag flag-like js-flag-like-2451 action-flag">
                            <div class="count-like"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
                    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
                        <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
                            <span></span>
              Test 1
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h3 class="syno21-actu-actu--subtitle">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">
                    <span data-quickedit-field-id="node/2451/title/fr/teaser">Promulgation de l'arrêté relatif au cahier des clauses simplifiées de cybersécurité</span>
                </a>
            </h3>

            <div class="syno21-actu-actu--body"></div>

            <div class="syno21-icon-plus">
                <a href="/securite-des-systemes-dinformation/promulgation-de-larrete-relatif-au-cahier-des-clauses" target="_blank">+</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>

</div>
```

My JS :

```
  var allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".syno21-teaser--wrapper .syno21-teaser--item");

      var vues = document.querySelector(".syno21-actu--vues");
      var likes = document.querySelector(".count-like");
      var favoris = document.querySelector(".syno21-actu--favoris a");

    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
      var element = allElements[i];

      for (var j = 0; j < element.children.length; j++) {
        // var child = element.children[i];
        // console.log("child", child);
        element_vues = element.getElementsByClassName("syno21-actu--vues")[0];
        element_likes = element.getElementsByClassName("count-like")[0];
        element_favoris = element.getElementsByClassName("use-ajax")[0];

      console.log("aaa :------------------ ",  element_favoris);

      }


      element_vues.innerHTML = '';
      favoris.innerHTML = '';
      element_favoris.innerHTML = '';

      console.log("---- ", element_favoris);
    }
```

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated full answer

```js
function removeOnlyText() {
  const allfavoris = document.querySelectorAll('.syno21-teaser--item .syno21-actu--favoris');

  allfavoris.forEach(favoris => {

    const anchor = favoris.querySelector('a');
    //Get all other html elements/tags
    const otherElements = anchor.querySelectorAll('*');
    //Empty everything
    anchor.innerHTML = '';
    //Reinsert only html elements/tags
    otherElements.forEach(otherElement => anchor.appendChild(otherElement));

  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="removeOnlyText()">Remove only text</button>

<div class="syno21-teaser--item">

  <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
      <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
        <span>This is a span element, don't remove</span>
        Ajouter aux favoris
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
      <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
        <span>This is a span element, don't remove</span>
        Ajouter aux favoris
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
      <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
        <span>This is a span element, don't remove</span>
        Ajouter aux favoris
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
      <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
        <span>This is a span element, don't remove</span>
        Ajouter aux favoris
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please take a look to my js, i cant use anchor (which is 'favoris' in my case) with element.getElementsByClassName

Comment: The OP wants to preserve the `<span>` element.

Comment: @SameerKhan thanks, but it works only for one item, here i have div (`.syno21-teaser--item`), each one have `<div class="syno21-actu--favoris">`

Comment: @SameerKhan i added a screenshot

Comment: @mitsu Updated answer with multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

Remove children nodes of type text:

```js
const removeText = (element) => {
  element.childNodes
    .forEach( child => {
      if(child.nodeName === '#text')
        child.remove()
    });
}

// ...
      removeText(element_vues);
      removeText(favoris);
      removeText(element_favoris);

      /* Alternative:
      [element_vues, favoris, element_favoris]
        .forEach( removeText )
      */
// ...
```

You can even make it recursive, so it removes all text nodes from the node and all its descendants:

```js
// Defaults to NOT recurse to maintain syntax with above version
const removeText = (element, recursive=false) => {
  element.childNodes
    .forEach( child => {
      if(child.nodeName === '#text') {
        child.remove()
      }
      else if (recursive && child.childNodes.length) {
        removeText(child, recursive);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, I had you voted up because your strategy was even better than mine and because you beat Samuli Hakoniemi to the punch.  But I retracted because I think your edit, although more generic, made it less clear.

Comment: I just integrated into the new code posted by the OP edit....

Comment: I must not have seen the edit when I did this.  Have your +1.  Although just so you know I think you may need to put braces around our forEach lambda body.

Comment: Braces added around `forEach` lambda body.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways. The simple way is to clear `.innerText` property. But if you want to play safe, you should traverse through the `childNodes` of an element and then remove the child node, if it's "type" is **text**:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');

console.log(`before --- textContent: "${a.textContent}"`, `childNode: ${a.children[0]}`);

a.childNodes.forEach((node) => node.nodeName.includes('#text') && node.remove());

console.log(`after --- textContent: "${a.textContent}"`, `childNode: ${a.children[0]}`);
```

```html
<a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451?destination&amp;token=b9Wrl6d8m3LsUnQSjMtJVIijAc4Yxc4x-Ky1JX4rwr4" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
  <span></span>
  Ajouter aux favoris
</a>
```

Comment: Hey @Samuli, this works but just for one item in allElements :(

Answer (score 0):

You could add your text in a tag with an id and removing the text from it

```js
    const text = document.getElementById("fav");
    text.innerHTML = "";
```

```html
     <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
        <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
           <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
            <span></span>
            <span id="fav">Ajouter aux favoris</span>
          </a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: can't do that, i do not have accès to the html, i have to do that only in js

Comment: so innerText is you answer I guess

Comment: InnerText removes tags too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32247904/15335954 should do the trick so

Comment: it works but only for one item in allElements :(

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this warps the link text and make it unique by decorating **id** then follow mentioned simple step

```
const text = document.getElementById("link-text-id");

text.innerHTML = "";
 

 <div class="syno21-actu--favoris">
    <div class="flag flag-favoris js-flag-favoris-2451 action-flag">
       <a title="" href="/flag/flag/favoris/2451" class="use-ajax" rel="nofollow">
        <span></span>
        <span id="link-text-id">Ajouter aux favoris</span>
      </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this will be help full to you

Comment: Charles Lavalard already gave this answer and the OP said he wasn't able to change the HTML.